# Why Soundwire server application doesn't give out any sound, just echoing my voice?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Using Ubuntu 20.04 and just installed Soundwire aaplication, as my speaker wasn't working, I installed `PulseAudio Volume Controller` and `portaudio` then also when I connect to my mobile device I can't hear any voice output just my own audio is echoing in a horrible way, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, just switch the ALSA in the pulse audio controller which can be found in the Soundwire Application, [like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvjTu.png), to another mic, and voila!